# Convert MKMapRect to MKPolyline

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a `MKMapRect` and would like to convert it to a `MKPolyline` and put it on the map.  I'm getting a result but my polyline is showing completely off (way too far north, way too far east) to where it should be.

```
MKMapPoint *points = calloc(5, sizeof(MKMapPoint));

points[0] = MKMapPointMake(myMapRect.origin.x,myMapRect.origin.y);
points[1] = MKMapPointMake(myMapRect.origin.x-myMapRect.size.height,myMapRect.origin.y);
points[2] = MKMapPointMake(myMapRect.origin.x-myMapRect.size.height,myMapRect.origin.y+myMapRect.size.width);
points[3] = MKMapPointMake(myMapRect.origin.x,myMapRect.origin.y+myMapRect.size.width);
points[4] = MKMapPointMake(myMapRect.origin.x,myMapRect.origin.y);

MKPolyline *polygonLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:points count:5];
```

Is this the best way to go about this and why is it not coming up properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is the right way.

(Replaced the `-` with `+` and `width` with `height`)

```
points[0] = MKMapPointMake(myMapRect.origin.x,myMapRect.origin.y);
points[1] = MKMapPointMake(myMapRect.origin.x+myMapRect.size.width, myMapRect.origin.y);
points[2] = MKMapPointMake(myMapRect.origin.x+myMapRect.size.width,myMapRect.origin.y+myMapRect.size.height);
points[3] = MKMapPointMake(myMapRect.origin.x,myMapRect.origin.y+myMapRect.size.height);
points[4] = MKMapPointMake(myMapRect.origin.x,myMapRect.origin.y);
```

Comment: Thanks Gonzo,  I did this initially and ended up playing with a few other configurations.  This is the correct configuration.  Turns out I wasn't generating my MKMapRect properly, go figure!